# In VHDL, check if an access is null from an if statement?

Tags: vhdl

Let's why i have a fun1 that may or may write to a line access type... then later i want to deference this line access and use it but... now i have no idea if the access reference is null or has data behind it.  How can i use an if statement to check if an access type is null or has data behind it?

```vhdl
use std.textio.all;

entity test2 is
end entity;

architecture beh of test2 is
    
    procedure fun1(
        variable x: inout line
    ) is
    begin
    
    end procedure;
    
    procedure fun2(
        variable x: in string
    ) is
    begin
        report x severity note;
    end procedure;
            
begin
    
    process
        variable x :line;
    begin
        --doing something with x... or leave null....
        fun1(x);
        
        --How to check if x is null so that i can put an if statement around this?
        fun2(x.all);
    
    end process;

end architecture;
```

```
PS> C:\questasim64_2020.4\win64\vcom.exe -2002 test2.vhd

PS> C:\questasim64_2020.4\win64\vsim.exe -c test2 
ERROR: Attempting to dereference a null access value
Time: 0 ps  Iteration: 0  Process: /test2/line__24
  File: C:/Users/wpmoore/Desktop/sandbox1/test2.vhd

HDL Line: C:/Users/wpmoore/Desktop/sandbox1/test2.vhd:31
exit 2
INFO: [Common 17-206] Exiting xsim at Tue Mar 22 12:33:16 2022...
code:(1)
```

Comment: "Error: Attempting to dereference a null access value" occurs when the  fun2 procedure call parameter actual x.all is evaluated. IEEE Std 1076-2008 8. Names, 8.1  General "... The evaluation of a name that has a prefix includes the evaluation of the prefix, that is, of the corresponding name or function call. If the type of the prefix is an access type, the evaluation of the prefix includes the determination of the object designated by the corresponding access value. In such a case, it is an error if the value of the prefix is a null access value. ..."

Answer (score 3):

VHDL has the keyword `null`. As well as meaning "no action" as a one liner, can be used to check if an object of access type is null to prevent dereferencing a null pointer and getting an error:

```vhdl
variable l: line;

...

if l = null then
  report "l is null - doing nothing";
else
  report "l.all = " & l.all;
end if;
```